# HTML: children must not be allowed to overflow their father

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a div with two children which, thanks to the jQuery UI library, are resizable.

The problem is that when you resize one of the two children, the other child overflows the father.

What I want is that overflow is not allowed. With "not allowed" I don't mean overflow:hidden. Overflow must not be allowed.

Here you have a demo in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t8c1q1gm/

NOTE: I'd like to have a CSS solution rather than a javascript one.

HTML CODE

```
<div id="parent">
  <div>

  </div>

  <div>

  </div>
</div>
```

CSS code

```
#parent{
  height:891px;
  width:630px;
  margin-bottom:1000px;
}

#parent > div
{
  border-color:red;
  height:20%;
}
```

JS code

```
var children = document.querySelector("#parent").querySelectorAll("div");

for(var k=0; k<children.length; k++)
{
    $(children[k]).resizable({ containment: "parent" });
}
```

Comment: Basically, you want the children which isn't be resized to stay in its place?

Comment: @Roysh the child which isn't be resized must be compressed so that it doesn't overflow, or alternatively the resizing of the element must stop to avoid overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Roysh's answer is great but I just wanted to add that I noticed there was a small bug because the `resize` event is only called if the div is actually resized (for example if you drag down but the div is already at max height then the size cannot change and `resize` event doesn't get called which means you would have to drag up a bit first before being able to drag down again).

So I'm using the `start` event instead which is called as soon as you click to resize the div. This makes the process more consistent.

```
var children = document.querySelector("#parent").querySelectorAll("div");

for(var k=0; k<children.length; k++)
{
    $(children[k]).resizable({
        start: function() {
            var maxHeight = $("#parent").height() - $(this).siblings().height();
            $(this).resizable("option", "maxHeight", maxHeight)
        },
        containment: "parent" });
}
```

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t8c1q1gm/3/

Comment: Nice one @Redtama!

Comment: Thanks @Roysh! Nice one to you too! :)

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you need

```
var children = document.querySelector("#parent").querySelectorAll("div");

for(var k=0; k<children.length; k++)
{
    $(children[k]).resizable({ containment: "parent" });
    $(children[k]).resize(function() {
      var j = $("#parent").height() - $(this).siblings().height();
      $(this).css('max-height',j);
    });
}
```

fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/t8c1q1gm/